# Azure Redis Cache : No connection is available to service this operation; An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: azure-redis-cache

i am implementing Azure Redis Cache to solve session issue for my Azure hosted application below is the code i written.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSyfu.png)

do we need to do any confiuration changes for Redis in Azure portal.
please help.

[image]

Comment: What port are you using in your connection string?

Comment: it is 6380 Marlow : <RedisCAcheName>:6380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some test on my side and this is my test console app code :

```
using System;
using StackExchange.Redis;


namespace redistest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SetString("id","abcd");

        }

        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyRedisConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("<connection string>");
        });

        public static void SetString(string key ,string value)
        {
            var con = lazyRedisConnection.Value;
            IDatabase db = con.GetDatabase();
            db.StringSet(key,value);

            Console.WriteLine(db.StringGet("id"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Result :

[image]

Seems everything works as excepted. I got the same error in the beginning:

> No connection is available to service this operation

It is due to Azure Redis service has not been created yet. it will take several minutes to finish this process. You can check its status here :
[image]

When its status is Running, you can try to connect to it.

In the whole process, I have no additional configs for my Redis service,all I have done is: create Redis=>wait it be created => find the connection string => connect to it by code.

Actually I configed nothing on my Redis. Everything works for me. I am not sure if it is related to the version of `StackExchange.Redis`, some people get this error when using 2.xx version and when they get back to 1.2.6, this issue is no longer appears . You can have a try. Hope it helps.

Comment: the same error i got, and the status of redis is running, added images for reference in the top. i have added my IP also i Redis Firewall Gong.  do i need to do any more

Comment: Hi @SAIkrishna, if you still facing the same issue,rising a support ticket from Azure portal will be a good idea:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: Thank you Gong, will raise a support ticket.

Comment: Gong, this issue happening only with my restricted network access , it is working as expected from my home network. what may b the issue . is it because of  company restricted networ , if yes what may be resolution Gong

Comment: @SAIkrishna, I see, thanks for the information. If you have found the root reason, pls mark my post as an answer to close this question . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

the same error i got, and the status of redis is running, added images for reference
[image]

[image]

i have added my IP also in the Redis Firewall.

did i need to do any thing more Gong.

Comment: Hi , I have appended the update in my previous answer , pls take a look

Comment: i have degraded the Nuget package to 1.2.6 Gong, still the same issue Persists. attached packages.config in my first post Gong.